# File Size Vs. Image Size

Tags: image-quality, file-size

I want to reduce the size an image in order to get it to fit on a online program I'm using for an experiment. However, the issue with this is that it reduces the file size, which I need to stay the same. Is there a way of editing the image size of a photo without reducing the file size or the resolution?

Comment: Welcome Anna!  It's difficult to understand what you mean when you use "size" for both kb and dimensions. "Resolution" can also either mean ppi, or dimensions - depending on who uses the word. Are you wanting to keep the KB the same but reduce the dimensions? Or reduce KB and keep dimensions the same? Or are you wanting to keep PPI the same but reduce dimensions? Or wanting to keep PPI and dimensions the same but reduce KB (which won't happen)?

Comment: Thank you so much for your response! Yes I want to reduce the dimensions but keep the KB the same. For example if my file is 2MB and 4032 × 2268 pixels, I would like to keep it 2MB but reduce the it to 700 x 400 pixels.

Comment: Not sure that is possible. Why would you want that? There are less pixels and they take up less space on the disk.

Comment: What's the PPI of yor 4kx2k image? And what PPI are you aiming for on the 700x400 image? Most often the KB is of little concern. Dimensions and PPI are the primary things to consider in digital images. The 700px image will *naturally* take less MB/KB. Of course you can increase the PPI of the 700px image to force it to take up more KB.. but like @Wolff, I'm not certain *why* you would want to do that.

Comment: Hi! I'm running an experiment that requires three different levels of images at different file sizes. It can also be a measure of different resolutions, but there needs to be a large enough difference to see by the naked eye.

Comment: OK, so this is all for screen and not print, right? What confuses me is that the file size of an image is dictated by the number of pixels it contains. If you reduce the dimensions you also reduce the number of total pixels in the image. So naturally the file size will go down. So you would have to find some hacky way to add non-needed data to the image file, but I can't see how that would be helpful in any experiment.

Comment: I think the logic is flawed. Images with smaller dimensions, will have a smaller memory footprint. Any "hack" (and it would *have* to be some sort of "hack") to force a small image to have the same memory footprint would be unnatural and inconsequential since it won't *ever* happen in an actual working environment.

Comment: Yes this is for screen and not print! Yeah, the experiment is a bit complicated to explain, but I basically need the image to be 700px by 400px in order to fit the online program, but I want to keep the resolution quality and file size the same.

Comment: Resolution, files size, and quality are *all* dependent upon each other. They are not independent factors which can be adjusted without altering the other two factors.

Comment: The pixels on your screen all have the same size. You can't have different resolutions on the same screen. A smaller image simply has less pixels and can't be "sharper" (have more details per area) than another image.

Comment: Stop adding comments here. If you need to clarify something do it on the original question.

Comment: You are essentially asking how to take an 18 wheel Mack truck, make it fit into a parking space for a Toyota Prius, but still look like a full size Mack Truck...... ain't gonna happen.

Comment: If you reduce the physical size of a raster image, that means less pixels. Less pixels = less data = smaller file size. You can't have your cake and eat it too.

Answer (score 3):

**There is no way to do that.**

If you have an uncompressed file format the file size will reduce depending on the pixel dimensions.

If you have a compressed format it is really complicated trying to guess the file size, because this depends on the content of the image, the algorithm, the compression settings, and also the pixel dimension.

The only way is having **different images**, randomly choosing two that have a 2Mb file size.

---

On your comments, you are adding more and more terms that has nothing to do with file size:

> I want to keep the resolution quality and file size the same.

There is no such "resolution quality" Quality is a process, and each file can have an assigned resolution and have a good quality for the intended objective. You can have a good quality wallpaper for a 4k monitor and having a good quality one for an HD screen, or even have a good quality thumbnail. All of them being different sizes (for now, resolution).

Besides that file size is about DATA and how it is arranged and packed. You can have a very bad photo of 10Mb and a masterpiece on 2Mb. All it counts to the file size is the data (pixels) and how they are arranged (compression).

Comment: You might want to add that resolution on a digital display is number of pixels so if you reduce pixels then you have decreased resolution. And PPI does not come to play on a monitor.